# Drupal max-age=0

Tags: caching, proxies

Trying to setup the Varnish cache with our drupal installation. Issue is that with all pages, it's sending max-age=0. I've set this in the setttings.php

```
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 3600;
```

But whenever I try and view the setting in drupal, I get:

[image]

Which even when I set it to any value instead of `<none>`, it just stays as`<none>`.

Not sure what's going on!

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but it's my understanding that Varnish (and any other external caching system) will use the `page_cache_maximum_age` value (the next selection on `admin/config/development/performance`) for its cache lifetime whereby Drupal will use the one mentioned in your question to manage its internal page cache.

Comment: If that is the case, then it seems strange to me still that the max-age=0 is still being set on an anonymous user. This is obviously blocking varnish from caching it, and providing a huge load on the server for it. Any idea how to correct for the max-age=0 from being set?

Comment: when you surf over to `admin/config/development/performance` on your system, what are you setting the second cache parameter to, eg the one labeled `Expiration of cached pages` and with the description `The maximum time an external cache can use an old version of a page.`?  Or are you on Drupal 6 and not seeing this?

Comment: Settings are as follows. Minimum cache lifetime: <none>, Expiration of cached pages: 6 hours, Cache pages for anonymous users: YES, Cache blocks: YES.

Comment: ok, can you do access your site via curl?  and if so include the output of `curl -I www.example.com/node/1` or something similar in your question?  because out of the box "this just works" but it is sounding like some module you have installed is doing something somewhere and perhaps it will leave some trail in the headers...

Comment: Here is the root: http://pastebin.com/KTNrXBXz. Here is a node: http://pastebin.com/RF6pNgcX. Note, varnish is currently being bypassed, as max-age would disallow varnish caching anyways.

Comment: Got'm.  If you go and curl various sites you will notice that the cache control header is usually sent fairly early in the transaction.  In yours it is the last sent, and that makes me think something in there module wise or server set up wise is sending it and possibly overriding one sent via Drupal.  Alas this suggests a lot more work that I don't think I will be able to remotely help out with (and then there is that oddity about setting the 3600 that doesn't work that further suggests something else going on here) but I hope some of this might give you an "a-ha" moment.

Answer (score 5):

The settings in settings.php will override any configurations you (try) to choose in the Drupal UI: /admin/config/development/performance .

```
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 0;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 21600;
```

These two settings would override whatever cache timings you set in the Drupal UI.

The maximum_age setting (for example 6 hours) will display in your headers as:

> Cache-Control:public, max-age=21600

After making changes to the max-age and clearing the cache, if you do not see the changes reflected in the Response Headers it may be worth looking towards nginx for the answer.

As per Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002567/nginx-add-header-and-cache-control .
It does provide good information about how cache headers are, or can be set in Nginx.